# Can't connect to android adb

Tags: android, networking, tcp, developer-tools

I am running adb on the command line and I'm trying to connect my Amazon firestick, but no luck. I have connected to my device in the past but for some reason I can not connect my device anymore.

I recently updated to Windows 10 and since then the command line says my device is offline.  Maybe it has something to do with the firewall settings but I can't seem to find anything of that matter.

The terminal says my fire stick is connected but states that it is offline. Here's what my command line says when I try to connect:

```
adb connect 192.168.1.6
STARTING DAEMON IT NOW ON PORT 5037
"DAEMON STARTED SUCCESSFULLY"
CONNECTED TO 192.168.1.6:5555
adb devices 
LIST OF  DEVICES ATTACHED
192.168.1.6:5555   OFFLINE
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You are connected then, seems like you have usb debugging disabled, or your PC SHA1 key hasnt been approved. If you have reinstalled windows you should look at the second option.